# How can I stop my MAC address from being seen as a number?

Tags: powershell, mac-address, dhcp, windows-server-2016

I'm using a cmdlet to create a policy of allowed MAC inside a scope of the Windows Server 2016 DHCP service.

I have a C# code that generates the script with all the info and it's legit, the MAC addresses are correct, but PowerShell turns out to "translate" some address, like `8634971886e5` into `863497188600000`.

The generated statement is:

```
Add-DhcpServerv4Policy -Name Test -Condition OR -ScopeId 127.0.0.1 -MacAddress EQ,8634971886e5
```

If I quote it, it'll say that the operator EQ is missing.

```
Add-DhcpServerv4Policy -Name Test -Condition OR -ScopeId 127.0.0.1 -MacAddress "EQ,8634971886e5"
```

Comment: You're going to have to supply actual code before we can diagnose what's wrong with it.

Comment: Try putting the MAC in quotes

Comment: Looks like the MAC is being interpreted as a number. As Itchydon says: quote the string.

Comment: If I quote it like this:

Add-DhcpServerv4Policy -Name Test -Condition OR -ScopeId 127.0.0.1 -MacAddress "EQ,8634971886e5"

It says that the operator EQ is missing :(

Comment: What happens if you try this: Add-DhcpServerv4Policy -Name Test -Condition OR -ScopeId 127.0.0.1 -MacAddress '8634971886e5'

Comment: Still missing the operator EQ with single quotes.

Comment: Please edit your title, it says nothing about your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So according to the [documentation for `Add-DhcpServerv4Policy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590655(v=wps.630).aspx) `-MacAddress` is looking for a string array. The example they give is much the same as your own.

> ```
> PS C:\> Add-DhcpServerv4Policy -Name HyperVPolicy -Condition OR -MacAddress EQ,00155D*,000569*
> ```

However, as you have seen some of your MACs are being seen as numbers since they are not quoted/typed as strings. Comments have been telling you to quote the string but I think that is being done incorrectly. Don't quote the *entire* string but it's individual *elements* so that it is a string array. From your  comments

> ```
> Add-DhcpServerv4Policy -Name Test -Condition OR -ScopeId 127.0.0.1 -MacAddress "EQ,8634971886e5"
> ```

`-MacAddress` is being sent one string. The first element is not a comparator hence the error you were getting.

Instead it should be...

```
Add-DhcpServerv4Policy -Name Test -Condition OR -ScopeId 127.0.0.1 -MacAddress "EQ","8634971886e5"
```

[Your workaround obviously works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981491/3829407) fine but I wanted you to know what other were trying to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

I've added hyphens to the MAC and works great.

Thanks anyway!